# Is it safe to put php code for accessing a database in the same script that we have wrote the form

Tags: php, mysql

Is it  safe to put php code for accessing a database in the same script that we have wrote the form?  For example `$_PHP_SELF`...? I mean the fact that we stop need another script from a server (that no none can read)and using the same code on the same file doesnt this make everyone able to see the code and our passwords
for example `mysqli_connect("server","asdfsa",code"`......
thanks...

Comment: if your server is properly configured, your php code could never "leak out". it would always be executed and the user would only ever see the script's OUTPUT...

Comment: The worst thing that might happen is, that the user will see an error generated by php, but he wont see your code (even if i saw that happen once when rammstein was selling tickets in germany, the server was overloaded that much it fired out the php code). But that should not happen with a properly configured server.

Comment: You can also put your code in a file outside of your wwwroot. This will be read back into the code with a `include` or `require`. This can be a bit more protection. But if someone gets your FTP credentials, they would get into these files anyway.

Comment: If your server's administrator accidentally disabled `mod_php` then the user would get the source code to your file. That's another reason to store the database credentials out of the web root.

Comment: php code is executed on server side, it will only generates an output : html, js...